# web site connection slow

Tags: apache, http, png

I have apache web server and I have a django site on it.
The site use a lot of images (~50) png file.
When I refresh the page it is very slow until it come back again.

I tried to check with google developer tools network view and saw that my site have connection latency when I requesting the images..

I attached the screenshot - it is the top of the list and go on until the end..

Do you have any idea to reduce the delay?

http://2seat.co.il/static/timeline.png

Comment: another screen shot
http://2seat.co.il/static/timeline2.png

Answer (score 2):

If your images dont change often try using cache control headers so that your browser doesnt get the images from server every time you reload a page

Comment: can I set the server to tell the client to cache? or it is something i need to set in the browser?